# How to add a custom function in a jourde after a tour is closed?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, zurb-joyride

I am using [Joyride tour](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) for drupal using [joyride drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/joyride) . I wanted to implement a post callback functionality as given below in the code in the argument postRideCallback below
How can I add a custom function below ?

```
/* Setting your options to override the defaults */
$('#contentID').joyride({
  'tipLocation': 'bottom',         // 'top' or 'bottom' in relation to parent
  'nubPosition': 'auto',           // override on a per tooltip bases
  'scrollSpeed': 300,              // Page scrolling speed in ms
  'timer': 2000,                   // 0 = off, all other numbers = time(ms) 
  'startTimerOnClick': true,       // true/false to start timer on first click
  'nextButton': true,              // true/false for next button visibility
  'tipAnimation': 'pop',           // 'pop' or 'fade' in each tip
  'pauseAfter': [],                // array of indexes where to pause the tour after
  'tipAnimationFadeSpeed': 300,    // if 'fade'- speed in ms of transition
  'cookieMonster': true,           // true/false for whether cookies are used
  'cookieName': 'JoyRide',         // choose your own cookie name
  'cookieDomain': false,           // set to false or yoursite.com
  'tipContainer': body,            // Where the tip be attached if not inline
  'postRideCallback': $noop,       // a method to call once the tour closes
  'postStepCallback': $noop        // A method to call after each step
});
```

Comment: reference your function name instead of `$noop`.

Comment: I have added function name and where do I need to declare the function? as it is pretty confusing

Comment: declare it anywhere in same scope or higher level scope

Comment: thanks for the help. I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Just replace $noop with your custom function.

However, make sure that you have already defined your custom function before you reference it here.

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone In the argument postRideCallback, the default value is $noop.
This can be replaced by the function name of your function.
The function declaration should come before this function call.

Hope this clears things up!